# Prove the uniqueness of subtraction

Tags: arithmetic

I have to prove this proposition: Given $m,n \in\mathbb Z$, there exists one and only one $x \in\mathbb Z$ such that $m + x = n$. So, just to be sure: I am given an equation and asked to first prove the existence of solution x and then its uniqueness, right?

From what I understand, "uniqueness" simply means that if two solutions fit in the equation, they must be equal. I can only use the axioms for addition and multiplication and derived propositions.

Proof of existence:

\begin{align*}
m + x &= n\\
(-m) + (m + x) &= (-m) + n\\
(-m + m) + x &= (-m) + n\\
0 + x &= (-m) + n\\
x &= (-m) + n\\
\end{align*}

Hence, the solution x exists.

The second part seems too simple. Assuming that x can take two values, x1 and x2... Proof of uniqueness:
\begin{align*}
m + x1 &= n\\
m + x2 &= n\\
m + x1 &= m + x2\\
(-m) + (m + x1) &= (-m) + (m + x2)\\
(-m + m) + x1 &= (-m + m) + x2\\
0 + x1 &= 0 + x2\\
x1 &= x2
\end{align*}

Hence, the solution x is unique. What do you think? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $m+x_1=n$ and $m+x_2=n$. Then $m+x_1=m+x_2$ and so $x_1=x_2$ by left-cancellation. I think you did a great deal more work than you really needed to here, but it never hurts to try to be thorough.

Comment: I should note that this, of course, does not address the *existence* portion of your question; for that, you need to make use of whatever axioms are at your disposal (just as I used left-cancellation because I assumed you could use it).

Comment: But this is OP's proof, just replacing adding $-m$ to both sides and using associativity and $m+(-m)=0$ with the words 'by left-cancellation'. This is not something you should omit given that OP said "I can only use the axioms for addition and multiplication and derived propositions".

Comment: @user314 This is *far* more succinct. I mean the question really is meaningless without knowing what axioms or results you're allowed to use.

Answer (score 1):

You did a great job with your proof! Why?

Your strategy is in the page 58 of the edition 2014 of the book *"A Transition to Advanced Mathematics"*, written by Smith, Eggen and Andre.

***"PROOF OF (∃!x)P(x): 
(i) Prove that (∃x) P(x) is true. Use any method. 
(ii) Prove that (∀y)(∀z)[P(y) ∧ P(z) ⇒ y = z]. 
Assume that y and z are objects in the universe such that P(y) and P(z) are true. 
From (i) and (ii) conclude that (∃!x)P(x) is true."***

My proof would be:

Assume m, n, x, y, and z are integers; and m + x = n.

There exists a solution because:

-m + m + x = -m + n (-m is the inverse of m under addition.)

x = -m + n (-m + m = 0 because 0 is the identity element under addition.)

x = n - m (commutative property).

As a final step we will be prove the uniqueness of the solution.

Assume we have two differents solutions y and z.

y = n - m, and z = n - m

then

y = z.

For that reason, the solution is unique. Q.E.D.

Comment: @Johnathan Please give me your opinion about my new answer to your question "Prove the uniqueness of subtraction." I am learning to write answers.

Answer (score 1):

In your proof of existence you basically show that the equation 
$$m+x=n$$
is equivalent to the equation
$$x=(-m)+n$$
But it is clear that this last equation has one unique solution.
Hence you have actually already proved the uniqueness.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I am new to proofs, so why would x = (-m) + n also show uniqueness? Because a binary operation can only generate one element?

Comment: You have on the left hand side your unknown variable, and on the right hand side a well defined number. Such an equation has always a unique solution, which is given by the right hand side.

Comment: And yes, the binary operation $(a,b)\mapsto a+b$ goes from $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$. So you can say that it generates one element.